# For a dataframe, convert all list in a column to int values

Tags: python, database, dataframe

My current daraframe is:

```
id   name    class
1     A      [1, 1, 1]
2     B      [2, 2]
3     C      [3]
4     D      [6,6]
```

all elements in any list will be the same so instead of exploding, we can join only the first element.

All I want my dataframe to look something like this:

```
id   name    class
1     A        1
2     B        2
3     C        3
4     D        6
```

Please help me how can I code this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Asuming there is atleast 1 element in the list you can apply a lambda function to the `class` column and set it to the 0th index.

#### Code

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 
    'class': [ [1,1,1], [2,2], [3], [6, 6]]
})

df['class'] = df['class'].apply(lambda x: x[0])   # Add this to your code
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. But my dataframe is very large, I can't specify each and every value.
Can you suggest a solution that changes all the "class" values by iterating over it?

Comment: @yodacoder I am not specifying each and every value. That is just initializing the dataframe. I am doing exactly as you said, iterating over the `class` values and choosing the 0th index.